# Google Chrome infinite scroll

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

I am using Google Chrome `Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` on `macOS Mojave 10.14.5`.

Every now and then web pages end up scrolling either up or down infinitely on Chrome. It seems to happen in random, I am not able to reproduce it at will, and I am not sure if it happens only on particular web pages or not. Here is a screenshot from gitlab:

[image]

This page actually does not have that whitespace at top but I can just scroll up and up forever. When I restart Chrome, I will most likely be not able to reproduce it, but in a few days it will happen again.

The only extension I have installed is `JSONView` which I do not think has anything to do with this.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade your version of Chrome to the latest (version 77)?

Comment: Can you disable JSONView then see if the problem manifests by itself after a few days?

Comment: i have the same issue, have you figure out what cause it?